# How to convert a C++ vector to a numpy array or how to move a vector pointer back and forth between C++, Cython and Python?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, vector, cython

The problem was, that I had a C++ vector and needed to convert it to a numpy array. The vector was from an external library. All I could sanely do, was to add an extra function into the source and recompile it again to the original DLL. The idea was, that I import the function with ctypes, then call it with a void pointer pointer and let the C++ function insert the vector pointer. 
Here started the first problems. I was only able to send a pointer back to Python by explicitly allocating memory. Not only needed I to use

```
myVec = new vector<T>
```

even for an int pointer I needed to use

```
myIntP = new int
```

Simply doing

```
x = 10
int* myIntP = &x
*pythonIntPP = myIntP
```

will not work. Back in Python, I will still have the original pointer.

```
**pythonIntPP = x
```

will work, though.

Why do I have to allocate memory for a pointer?

Anyway, let's get to the solution I found:
First, you will have a C++ function in a DLL that accepts a void**.
In Python do

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(r"C:\path\to.dll")
gvp = lib.GetVectorPointer
gvp.restype = c_int
gvp.argtypes = [POINTER(c_void_p), POINTER(c_int)] # we need the vector pointer and size
voidPP = pointer(c_void_p())
sizeP = pointer(c_int())
gvp(voidPP, sizeP)
```

Now we have the vector pointer and size in a Python object, but we can't unpack the pointer in Cython. So, we need create a cdef function, export it in a DLL (pyd file) and again import it within Python.

In Cython we do

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

from libcpp.vector cimport vector

ctypedef vector[T] Vec
ctypedef myVec* VecP
ctypedef VecP* VecPP

arr = np.empty(1, dtype=np.uint8)

def allocate_arr(size):
    arr.resize(size, refcheck=False)

cdef public int vec_to_numpy(void** voidPP):
    cdef VecP vecp= <VecP>ppVoid[0]
    cdef int size = vecp[0].size()
    cdef np.ndarray[T, ndim=1] data = arr # arr needs to be allocated 
    cdef int i
    for i in range(size):
        data[i] = vecp[0][i]

    return 0
```

In Python we can now call this function and get the array

```
lib = windll.LoadLibrary(r"C:\path\to\module.pyd")
v2n = lib.vec_to_numpy
v2n.restype = c_int
v2n.argtypes = [POINTER(c_void_p)]
import module
module.allocate_arr(sizeP) # allocate first
v2n(voidPP) # send the vector pointer to the Cython function

module.arr # this is the numpy array with the vector data
```

TIP:
You can tell the linker to export your Cython function with one of two hacks.
Write this line for every function to export at the beginning of your code (change names accordingly).

```
cdef void emit_pragma 'foo ();\n#pragma comment(linker, "/export:vec_to_numpy=vec_to_numpy")\nstatic void unused' ():pass
```

or use this hack in your function definition (use __stdcall to avoid name mangling).

```
cdef int vec_to_numpy 'unused;\nextern "C" __declspec(dllexport)  public int __stdcall vec_to_numpy' (void** voidPP):
```

Do you know of better ways to have full flexibility between those three languages?

Is there a simpler way to export symbols, so that they can be imported into Python that doesn't involve hacking? Being able to use cdef function directly in Python is very handy to me.

Comment: Could you set the `numpy` array buffer (`data`) pointer to `vecp`?  In Python it is possible to `x.data = y.data`, in effect giving `x` access to `y`s values.  I've used it to 'set' values of structured arrays from regular arrays.